# Objective C: How can I refactor this long if - else statement?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This if/else statement takes up a huge chunk of my class and quite frankly it is annoying. Is there any way I can make this much smaller and less code? This is just an example of my actual code, but if someone can help me down size this, I can apply it to my actual code.

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    if ([self.currentSearchStr length] == 0) {

        phoneViewController = [[viewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController"
                                                               bundle:nil
                                                                 list:self.list
                                                                index:indexPath.row
                                                                title:self.title];
    } else {
        phoneViewController = [[viewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController1"
                                                                bundle:nil
                                                                  list:self.list1
                                                                 index:indexPath.row
                                                                 title:self.title];
    }

} else {

    if ([self.currentSearchStr length] == 0) {

        padViewController = [viewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController"
                                                            bundle:nil
                                                              list:self.list
                                                             index:appDelegate.mSelectedRow
                                                             title:self.title];

    } else {

        padViewController = [[viewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController1"
                                                              bundle:nil
                                                                list:self.list1
                                                               index:appDelegate.mSelectedRow
                                                               title:self.title];
    }
```

Comment: Well, the first thing to do is to properly indent it, so you can tell what you're doing.

Comment: Beyond that, there doesn't appear to be anything "wrong".  There are only 3 `if` statements, and the nesting is nicely regular.

Comment: @DaveWood -- There are 3 `if` statements.  He is missing at least one `[`, however.

Comment: I reformatted it, sorry about that stackoverflow didn't transfer my code indentions correctly. I was afraid of that :(

Comment: Still not indented correctly.  And that style of `{}` formatting is poor.

Comment: Use expanded tabs for the interwebs

Comment: One might observe that the overall effect of the code is to alloc/init a VC for `padViewController`.  Rather than code that alloc/init 4 times it might be better to use the `if` statements to set up the parameters, then just do a single alloc/init at the end.  Or observe that the 1st and 3rd alloc/inits are identical, as are the 2nd and 4th, reducing down to only two cases.

Comment: do you need a separate padviewcontroller and phoneviewcontroller since only one of them can exist at the same time? do both controllers have the same class interface?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can refactor like this? Use `? :`

```
BOOL searchEmpty = [self.currentSearchStr length] == 0;
BOOL isIPhone = [UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone;

Class ViewControllerCls = searchEmpty ? [ViewController class] : [ViewController1 class];
NSString* nibName = searchEmpty ? @"viewController" : @"viewController1";
NSArray* list = searchEmpty ? self.list : self.list1;

NSInteger index = isIPhone ? indexPath.row : appDelegate.mSelectedRow;

viewController = [[ViewControllerCls alloc] initWithNibName:nibName
                                                     bundle:nil
                                                       list:list
                                                      index:index
                                                      title:self.title];
```

Comment: Very clean answer. 

Comment: @childhoodAndy I think you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525232/replacing-calayer-and-cabasicanimation-with-skscene-and-skactions/38528135?noredirect=1#comment65166334_38528135. Though it's not related to this question it's related to the DBMetaballLoading

Comment: @childhoodAndy Just a reminder :). The question is related to the DBMetaballLoading github project you worked on. Someone also put a 100 point bounty on it

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: I much prefer Childhood Andy's answer since it's a much cleaner version of my own, but I'll leave this one up so you can understand the if-else logic behind Andy's `?:` statements.*

---

Yes, you can definitely condense your logic by setting your `initWithNibName:` parameters as per the conditions before inserting them into your single `initWithNibName:` statement.

```
NSString *nibName;
NSArray *list;
if ([self.currentSearchStr length] == 0) {
    nibName = @"viewController";
    list = self.list;
} else {
    nibName = @"viewController1";
    list = self.list1;
}

int index;
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    index = indexPath.row;
} else {
    index = appDelegate.mSelectedRow;
}

padViewController = [[viewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:nibName
                                                      bundle:nil
                                                        list:list
                                                       index:index
                                                       title:self.title];
```

Answer (score 0):

This one particular case can be refactored down to one call of initWithNibName, with parameters as variables (as other answers have shown).

However if this type of code is all over, consider breaking the file into two subclasses, one for iPad and one for iPhone. Common code can live in the base class. Breaking the class up like this isn't always the right thing to do, but it is worth considering (ideally before the single file gets too large!).